# How do I find the library containing org.springframework.stereotype.Service?

Tags: spring, maven

Trying to import `import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;` I get *cannot resolve symbol stereotype*. As I understand it, I should be able to get the required dependency using Maven.

However... how do I find out which dependency to get -- i.e. the name of the dependency? That is, which library contains this library and how would I go about finding out?

Comment: Google search org.springframework.stereotype.Service jar

Answer (score 18):

It's the spring-context jar that your need. Add the following to your maven dependencies..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This example is referencing the latest version of the jar available at the moment but you should match the version with the version of spring that you want.

Comment: I have that in my dependencies (the most recent version), and I still get "cannot resolve symbol Service".

Comment: @VratislavJindra can you send me your project or sample project? This should not be happening so I'm assuming you have something else going on.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. In IntelliJ IDE, in the Maven Projects window, I had the project that was giving me troubles greyed out. Apparently it was ignored. Right clicking on it and selecting "Unignore Projects" fixed it. I don't recall ignoring it in the first place, but that was the cause of the issue. It's all fine now. Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: Due my company using their own repository and setting our environment to force us to use it, we don't have access to external repositories. Thanks for providing the jar. It made it easier to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this site : http://www.findjar.com/

Just past your class name (entire path org.spri...)

Comment: Thanks for that -- an invaluable resource.  Why didn't I find this question 3 years back _lol_

Answer (score 3):

You need to import this dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Note that the version number can be omitted if you use the parent module of Spring Boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

where *1.4.3.RELEASE* is the latest version of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Google search

> org.springframework.stereotype.Service jar

and then do a search [here](http://search.maven.org/) for the maven dependency configuration

Comment: FWIW, googling "org.springframework.stereotype.Service" now leads to this question as a first result. Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create DynamicWebProject, if you are using a Java Project and added that Maven dependency it would not work. Anyway, you dont need a separate dependency, its part of the spring-context already

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So, if I do have a Java Project, what would be the solution to this problem? Or is there simply non and you just have to have a DynamicWebProject?